# Rotation Axis Choice for a Rolling Disk (no slipping)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let's consider a disk rolling on a flat surface without sliding and an observer at rest (lab reference frame) starring at the disk motion. My understanding is that the observer can easily assess that the disk is indeed **rotating**. But about which axis? I don't think there is a single answer. For example, we could talk about 
a) Rotation about the center of mass CM combined with a translation of the CM at speed $v_{CM}$.
b) Rotation about the contact point $C$ which has instantaneous velocity equal to zero.
c) Rotation about an arbitrary point $P$ combined with translation at velocity $v_P$.

The $CM$, $C$, $P$ represent all centers of rotation (all instantaneous?) but point $C$, the contact point has zero velocity. Does the zero instantaneous velocity ICR provide any advantage?

In all three cases, do the other body points trace infinitesimal arc paths around the ICR at the same angular velocity $\omega$?

Thanks!